# Updating php5-mysql for MySQL 5.6 under Debian 7

Tags: mysql, php, debian, php5

After a lot of troubles installing MySQL 5.6 for Debian 7 (with ISPConfig)

(FYI, I followed this tutorial : http://xmodulo.com/2013/12/upgrade-mysql-server-debian-ubuntu.html)

my PHPMyAdmin shows me this message :

```
Your PHP MySQL library version 5.5.35 differs from your MySQL server version 5.6.16. This may cause unpredictable behavior.
```

I tried updating php5-mysql with aptitude, but officially I already have the lastest version... 
I would like to install php5-mysql with support for MySQL 5.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generally ignore this message, as long as the PHP MySQL library version is lower than the MySQL version, and they are both the same major version (here, 5).